# Firebase MLKit Eye Contour getPoints

Tags: android, firebase, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, eye-detection

I am trying to get the list of points from each eye detection using Firebase ML kit.

I have succeded to get the eye position of each eye (X, Y),

but when I try to call retrieve all points, it returns me an empty array. The code I am using is bellow which I tried different versions for the right and left eye from FirebaseVisionFaceContour.

```
for (FirebaseVisionFace face : faces)
                {
                    leftEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE);
                    if (leftEye != null) {
                        leftEyePos = leftEye.getPosition();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Left eye position: " + leftEyePos);

                    }

                    rightEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE);
                    if (rightEye != null) {
                        rightEyePos = rightEye.getPosition();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Right eye position: " + rightEyePos);

                    }
                    leftEyeContour = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.LEFT_EYE).getPoints();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Left eye contour: " + Arrays.toString(leftEyeContour));

                    rightEyeContour = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.RIGHT_EYE).getPoints();

                    for (int i=0; i<rightEyeContour.size(); i++){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Right eye contour: " + rightEyeContour.get(i).getX().toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Right eye contour: " + rightEyeContour.get(i).getY().toString());   
                    }
                }
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it and get all points of eye contour??

Answer (score 2):

To get all the face contour points, you have to enable ALL_CONTOURS in the options.

Comment: I have enabled them in the options. My problem is that I get an empty array of the points.

Comment: Is there any face in the image? The face contour is all or empty, which means it will return all the contour points or nothing. So make sure the whole face is present in the image